# How to bypass layout on homepage of the app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am using Sinatra and erb to create my first application. I've created a layout.erb, which is good for all the pages, except the homepage. In the homepage, i want a full-screen black block with a button in the middle. Nothing else.

Is there a way i can do that while being able to use the layout.erb on all the other pages?

My layout consist of only the bootstrap navbar for now.

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Germ Blog</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <a href="/logout" class="logout">Logout</a>
      <a href="/posts/new" class="logout">Add Post</a>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <%= yield %> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup, it's easy:

```
#my_app.rb

get '/' do
  ...

  erb :home, :layout => :home
  # or, for no layout, use `:layout => false`
end
```

Comment: Ah, thank you dax. I should've searched the sinatra docs properly before posting this. Lesson learnt. :)